# How to avoid specific paths in allShortestPath function?

Tags: neo4j

[image]

The graph is supposed to represent a system similar to github, with commits (commit1, commit2, commit3 and commit4), documents (d1, d2) and changes on those documents (green nodes).

I am trying to use CYPHER to get all the documents values at a specific commit. In other words, I am trying to find the shortest path between the specific commit and each of the documents on my graph, but avoiding some paths.

Imagine if I am on `commit4`, `d1` should be equal to `foo2` and `d2` should be equal to `spain`. This could be solved with the following CYPHER query:

```
MATCH (c:Commit {id: 'commit4'})-[:FOLLOWS|CHANGED*]->(:Value)<-[:EQUALS]-(d:Document), p = allShortestPaths((c)-[*]-(d))
RETURN p
```

This would give the following response:

[image]

Now, imagine that I want to be get the values on commit3. The request should not return any changes from the commit4. However, if I use the allShortestPaths function the way I do, it will go through commit4 since it is actually the shortest path to d1 and return the exact same response than if my starting node was commit4.

```
MATCH (c:Commit {id: 'commit3'})-[:FOLLOWS|CHANGED*]->(:Value)<-[:EQUALS]-(d:Document), p = allShortestPaths((c)-[*]-(d))
RETURN p
```

**How could I avoid the allShortestPath function to go through a [:FOLLOWS]->(c) relationship and solve my problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you explained, I understand that you don't want to traverse the `FOLLOWS` edge in the opposite direction of the edge. To do so you can use cypher projection in `algo.shortestPath`:

```
MATCH (start:Commit {name:'commit4'}) 
MATCH (end:Document)
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end, null,{
nodeQuery:'MATCH (n) RETURN id(n) AS id',
relationshipQuery:'MATCH (n)-[r:FOLLOWS|CHANGED]->(p) RETURN id(n) AS source, id(p) AS target UNION MATCH (n)-[r:EQUALS]-(p) RETURN id(n) AS source, id(p) AS target',
graph:'cypher'})
YIELD nodeId, cost
WITH end as document, algo.asNode(nodeId) AS value WHERE "Value" in labels(value)
return document, value
```

Replace `"commit4"` with any other commit name.